# undeploy an java application from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud

How can we un-deploy an application from GAE?
I don't want to delete the Project, instead I am trying to undeploy the app and use the same project to deploy completely different code.

Comment: Just deploy a new code, as a new version, then remove previous version. You need at least one version always deployed, but it can be simple one page html

Comment: @IgorArtamonov: Please, move this to an answer, so this question does not remain without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy a new code, as a new version, then remove previous version.

You need at least one version always deployed, but if you don't have any replacement at this moment you can deploy a simple one static page project.

Comment: Hi @IgorArtamonov, does Google still charge for the deployment of a static page project?